# Proof for replicating tiles

Tags: geometry, tessellations

A rep-tile is a shape which can be divided into n smaller shapes that are similar

E.g. a square can be reproduced by 4 smaller squares

rep-n means that a shape can be created from n smaller copies.

Therefore the square from earlier is rep-4

**Are all non-stellated rep-4 polygons also rep-9?**

Comment: How do you divide this one into 9 tiles? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl37T.gif